# Which WiFi dongle should I use?

Tags: networking, wireless

The issue here is that I need to buy a WiFi dongle for my new RPi. However, in the local market there are limited choices. I found:

1. [LB-LINK BL-LW05-AR5](http://dx.com/en/p/lb-link-bl-lw05-ar5-mini-150mbps-ieee802-11b-g-n-usb-2-0-wireless-wi-fi-adapter-w-5dbi-gain-antenna-203378#.Uvjn9PmSw3g)
2. [D-Link DWA-123](http://www.dlink.com.my/products/?idproduct=505&idCategory=270)
3. [ASUS USB-N13](http://www.asus.com/Networking/USBN13/#support)

**Which one should I use?** Please consider that I may use RPi as Access Point in my project so the dongle should support that.

Answer (score 1):

hostAPd will only work with the D-Link (RT5370) and the Asus (RT3072), so you should avoid the LB-Link (RTL8188CUS)

see this table for comparison:
https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Wireless_adapters/Chipset_table

I'm interested in your results too!

Comment: See also: http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters